# How to sort the items in mule dataweave2

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want to sort the below JSON items based on rank value from lower number to higher. Can someone suggest me with script to sort the items based on rank value

**Actual Payload**

```
{
 "content": {
  "status": "success",
  "mistatus": false,
  "offers": [
   {
    "id": "300",
    "name": "Internet 300",
    "offerings": [
     {
      "id": "1122334455",
      "name": "Internet 300",
      "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
       {
        "Default": 1,
        "count": 1
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
    "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
     {
      "name": "rank",
      "locdName": "rank",
      "valueType": "String",
      "value": [
       {
        "value": "3"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "Internet 10",
    "offerings": [
     {
      "id": "567890",
      "name": "Internet 10",
      "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
       {
        "Default": 1,
        "count": 1
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
    "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
     {
      "name": "rank",
      "locdName": "rank",
      "valueType": "String",
      "value": [
       {
        "value": "1"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": "200",
    "name": "Internet 200",
    "offerings": [
     {
      "id": "789078",
      "name": "Internet 200",
      "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
       {
        "Default": 1,
        "count": 1
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
    "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
     {
      "name": "rank",
      "locdName": "rank",
      "valueType": "String",
      "value": [
       {
        "value": "2"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

**Expected Payload**

```
{
 "content": {
  "status": "success",
  "mistatus": false,
  "offers": [
   {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "Internet 10",
    "offerings": [
     {
      "id": "567890",
      "name": "Internet 10",
      "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
       {
        "Default": 1,
        "count": 1
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
    "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
     {
      "name": "rank",
      "locdName": "rank",
      "valueType": "String",
      "value": [
       {
        "value": "1"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": "200",
    "name": "Internet 200",
    "offerings": [
     {
      "id": "789078",
      "name": "Internet 200",
      "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
       {
        "Default": 1,
        "count": 1
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
    "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
     {
      "name": "rank",
      "locdName": "rank",
      "valueType": "String",
      "value": [
       {
        "value": "2"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": "300",
    "name": "Internet 300",
    "offerings": [
     {
      "id": "1122334455",
      "name": "Internet 300",
      "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
       {
        "Default": 1,
        "count": 1
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
    "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
     {
      "name": "rank",
      "locdName": "rank",
      "valueType": "String",
      "value": [
       {
        "value": "3"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is always exactly one element in each `productOfferingCharacteristic` and `value` arrays you can just reference them using `[0]`. This solution will fail if there is a different number of elements in those arrays.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case offers at .content.offers -> offers orderBy($.productOfferingCharacteristic[0].value[0].value)
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "content": {
    "status": "success",
    "mistatus": false,
    "offers": [
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Internet 10",
        "offerings": [
          {
            "id": "567890",
            "name": "Internet 10",
            "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
              {
                "Default": 1,
                "count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
          {
            "name": "rank",
            "locdName": "rank",
            "valueType": "String",
            "value": [
              {
                "value": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "200",
        "name": "Internet 200",
        "offerings": [
          {
            "id": "789078",
            "name": "Internet 200",
            "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
              {
                "Default": 1,
                "count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
          {
            "name": "rank",
            "locdName": "rank",
            "valueType": "String",
            "value": [
              {
                "value": "2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "300",
        "name": "Internet 300",
        "offerings": [
          {
            "id": "1122334455",
            "name": "Internet 300",
            "bundledProductOfferingOption": [
              {
                "Default": 1,
                "count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "productOfferingCharacteristic": [
          {
            "name": "rank",
            "locdName": "rank",
            "valueType": "String",
            "value": [
              {
                "value": "3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```